# Entity Framework. Cannot retrieve data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I met very strange behavior and I really don't have idea what is this may related to. I tried to retrieve data two ways: pure LINQ and Stored Procedure but data just do not coming back. No errors or exceptions. On SQL Server side I can see from profiler that stored procedure was executed.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<OrdersDto>> GetAll(int userid)
{
    OrdersDto[] result;
    try
    {
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@UserId", userid);
        result = await _db.Database.SqlQuery<OrdersDto>("UserOrders @UserId", param).ToArrayAsync();
        //var result = await _db.Order.Where(x=> x.CustomerId == 1)
        //    .Include(x => x.OrderDetails)
        //    .Include(x => x.OrderStatus)
        //    .Include(x => x.PaymentStatus)
        //    .AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the connection string

Comment: Have you tried to run it synchronously? Just to see if it works?

Comment: @wandos, there is lot of the queries in application that working properly, so that's not connection string for sure.

Comment: @S.Akbari, nope, but this is good idea. Let me try.

Comment: What do you mean by *data is not coming back*? Also what is `OrdersDto` - entity model class or just class for holding the SP result?

Comment: @IvanStoev, this is exactly what I said - no exceptions and no data. Yes, OrdersDto, that's class to hold SP result.

Comment: @S.Akbari, you was right - synchroniously it's working, bu the question is why it's not working as async?

Comment: @andrey.shedko So, where do you check the `await` result? It might not still completed when you are checking it. Do you have a breakpoint at `await` line?

Comment: @S.Akbari, please add this comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `await` is reached, the thread is returned to the caller. When you are checking the `await` result, because you're not waiting for the completion of the task you are not getting the result. If you run your query synchronously you can see your desired result:

```
result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<OrdersDto>("UserOrders @UserId", param).ToArray();
```

There is no problem to run this code asynchronously, but you should check the result only when the task is completed: